# Stripe Live payment forms fetch GET testkey PHP

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I use Stripe Payments for my payment processing, I used the template https://stripe.com/docs/payments/quickstart for this.
Theoretically it should work that you change the testkeys to the livekeys so that the payments are real.

However, the GET fetch: **[https://api.stripe.com/v1/elements/sessions?key=pk_test_&type=payment_intent&locale=de-DE&client_secret=pi_3Ke0zTH20gE5OH0B0Q6LcTNu_secret_RSkfXqAv62pINkKGezxw6lKkk&expand[0]=payment_method_preference.payment_intent.payment_method](https://api.stripe.com/v1/elements/sessions?key=pk_test_&type=payment_intent&locale=de-DE&client_secret=pi_3Ke0zTH20gE5OH0B0Q6LcTNu_secret_RSkfXqAv62pINkKGezxw6lKkk&expand%5B0%5D=payment_method_preference.payment_intent.payment_method)**

is not set to the livekey and so the error code :

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "payment_intent_invalid_parameter",
    "doc_url": "https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/payment-intent-invalid-parameter",
    "message": "The client_secret provided does not match the client_secret associated with the PaymentIntent.",
    "param": "client_secret",
    "type": "invalid_request_error"
  }
}
```

My Code Looks like that:

*checkout.js*

```
const stripe = Stripe("pk_live_51KDuPRH20gE5OH0BFLY0lMyxu7alzpR4UfUXn4f5kvHYlkER2TXrOqjEmUNZVp8fHAvULpmBs3jJCVYjvSeM7pqj00aWt4gNAu");

// The items the customer wants to buy
const items = [{ id: "xl-tshirt" }];

let elements;

initialize();
checkStatus();

document
  .querySelector("#payment-form")
  .addEventListener("submit", handleSubmit);

// Fetches a payment intent and captures the client secret
async function initialize() {
  const { clientSecret } = await fetch("create.php", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    body: JSON.stringify({ items }),
  }).then((r) => r.json());

  elements = stripe.elements({ clientSecret });

  const paymentElement = elements.create("payment");
  paymentElement.mount("#payment-element");
}

async function handleSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  setLoading(true);

  const { error } = await stripe.confirmPayment({
    elements,
    confirmParams: {
      // Make sure to change this to your payment completion page
      return_url: "https://myred.love/map/success",
    },
  });

  // This point will only be reached if there is an immediate error when
  // confirming the payment. Otherwise, your customer will be redirected to
  // your `return_url`. For some payment methods like iDEAL, your customer will
  // be redirected to an intermediate site first to authorize the payment, then
  // redirected to the `return_url`.
  if (error.type === "card_error" || error.type === "validation_error") {
    showMessage(error.message);
  } else {
    showMessage("An unexpected error occured.");
  }

  setLoading(false);
}

// Fetches the payment intent status after payment submission
async function checkStatus() {
  const clientSecret = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get(
    "payment_intent_client_secret"
  );

  if (!clientSecret) {
    return;
  }

  const { paymentIntent } = await stripe.retrievePaymentIntent(clientSecret);

  switch (paymentIntent.status) {
    case "succeeded":
      showMessage("Payment succeeded!");
      break;
    case "processing":
      showMessage("Your payment is processing.");
      break;
    case "requires_payment_method":
      showMessage("Your payment was not successful, please try again.");
      break;
    default:
      showMessage("Something went wrong.");
      break;
  }
}

// ------- UI helpers -------

function showMessage(messageText) {
  const messageContainer = document.querySelector("#payment-message");

  messageContainer.classList.remove("hidden");
  messageContainer.textContent = messageText;

  setTimeout(function () {
    messageContainer.classList.add("hidden");
    messageText.textContent = "";
  }, 4000);
}

// Show a spinner on payment submission
function setLoading(isLoading) {
  if (isLoading) {
    // Disable the button and show a spinner
    document.querySelector("#submit").disabled = true;
    document.querySelector("#spinner").classList.remove("hidden");
    document.querySelector("#button-text").classList.add("hidden");
  } else {
    document.querySelector("#submit").disabled = false;
    document.querySelector("#spinner").classList.add("hidden");
    document.querySelector("#button-text").classList.remove("hidden");
  }
}
```

*create.php*

```
<?php
include('../includes/connection.php');
require 'vendor/autoload.php';



session_start();

// This is your test secret API key.
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_live_...');

function calculateOrderAmount(array $items): int {
    // Replace this constant with a calculation of the order's amount
    // Calculate the order total on the server to prevent
    // people from directly manipulating the amount on the client
    1400;
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');

try {
    // retrieve JSON from POST body
    $jsonStr = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $jsonObj = json_decode($jsonStr);

    // Create a PaymentIntent with amount and currency
    $paymentIntent = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::create([
        'amount' => calculateOrderAmount($jsonObj->items),
        'currency' => 'eur',
        'automatic_payment_methods' => [
            'enabled' => true,
        ],
    ]);

    $output = [
        'clientSecret' => $paymentIntent->client_secret,
    ];

    echo json_encode($output);
} catch (Error $e) {
    http_response_code(500);
    echo json_encode(['error' => $e->getMessage()]);
}
```

*payment.php*

```
<head>
   
    <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
    <script src="checkout.js" defer></script>
  </head>
<body>
<form id="payment-form" class="col-sm-12">
                                              <div id="payment-element">
                                                <!--Stripe.js injects the Payment Element-->
                                              </div>
                                              <hr class="my-4">
                                              <button class="buy-now btn btn-sm height-auto px-4 py-3 
                                              btn-primary" class="add-to-cart" id="submit">
                                                <div class="spinner hidden" id="spinner"></div>
                                                <span  id="button-text">Jetzt bezahlen</span>
                                              </button>
                                              <div id="payment-message" class="hidden"></div>
                                            </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Could you indicate the function call where the error is triggered?

Answer (score 0):

Same issue with react-stripe-js, is set the stripe promise with my pk_live but the session request use my pk_test key

```
    import { Elements } from '@stripe/react-stripe-js'
    import { loadStripe } from '@stripe/stripe-js/pure'
    
    const MyCheckout = ({customer}) => {

    const stripe= loadStripe(
        'pk_live_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
       )
    return <Elements options={options} stripe={stripe}>
         <Checkout
            clientData={{
            ...clientData,
            customerId: customer.id
            }}
            stripePromise={stripe}
          />
       </Elements>
     }
```

I can see POST /v1/payment_intents and customers request on my live stripe account then my back have the live secret key....

I work with AWS amplify and nextjs and everything works fine on my local env off course cannot replicate ... :(